# Qt5 Visual Studio 2012 unresolved external symbols to opengl

Tags: qt, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I've been trying to static link Qt application.

I've downloaded sources from git and successfully compiled them with following configure options :
configure -c++11 -mp -debug-and-release -static -angle -nomake tests -nomake examples -prefix C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012 -platform win32-msvc2012

But after I selected the version of Qt I got from compiling and tried to run I've gotten a lot of linker errors to opengl - some of them disappeared after I added Ws2_32.lib and opengl32.lib to linker, but several more - all starting with gl...

Are those functions not located in opengl32.lib ? From what I recall this .lib on windows is from opengl 1.1 and those functions seem to be newer - but why didn't I have such problems with normal Qt and what do I need to install/download/link to get it to work ?

```
1>Qt5Gui.lib(qopenglbuffer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glBindBuffer referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl QOpenGLBuffer::bind(void)" (?bind@QOpenGLBuffer@@QEAA_NXZ)
1>Qt5Gui.lib(qopenglbuffer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glBufferData referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QOpenGLBuffer::allocate(void const *,int)" (?allocate@QOpenGLBuffer@@QEAAXPEBXH@Z)
1>Qt5Gui.lib(qopenglbuffer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glBufferSubData referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QOpenGLFunctions::glBufferSubData(unsigned int,__int64,__int64,void const *)" (?glBufferSubData@QOpenGLFunctions@@QEAAXI_J0PEBX@Z)
1>Qt5Gui.lib(qopenglbuffer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glDeleteBuffers referenced in function "void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::freeBufferFunc(class QOpenGLFunctions *,unsigned int)" (?freeBufferFunc@?A0x6f2ce48a@@YAXPEAVQOpenGLFunctions@@I@Z)
1>Qt5Gui.lib(qopenglbuffer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glGenBuffers referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl QOpenGLBuffer::create(void)" (?create@QOpenGLBuffer@@QEAA_NXZ)
```

Comment: did you add QT+=opengl in .pro?

Comment: I use Qt5 Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.2 - it doesn't create .pro automatically,but I can generate it - and it contains "QT += core opengl widgets gui" for the default newly created Qt Application.

Comment: *"Are those functions not located in opengl32.lib?"* Bingo! Buffer Objects were added to GL in ***1.5***, that lib is written against ***1.1***. My only experience with Qt and extensions has been inheriting the `QGLFunctions` class, which effectively does the same thing as a dedicated extension loading library, only for a much smaller subset of the API. In any case, those functions have to be loaded at ***run-time*** by *something* on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: This is what QOpenGLBuffer does..

Comment: @paulm Clearly it does not, or those symbols would be defined. It must rely on another dependency.

Comment: It clearly does: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/4273c14e57d26cf2dde90ed9db1f463a25b327bd:src/gui/opengl/qopenglbuffer.cpp

Comment: @paulm Nope, the code you listed ***clearly*** has an entirely separate dependent class called `QOpenGLExtensions` doing that. Which brings me back to my initial point.

Comment: @paulm `QOpenGLBuffer` does not put those symbols at global scope. It relies on a separate class to load the extension, but then also goes through an instance of that class everytime it calls one of the functions. The linker is complaining about GL API calls not qualified with a class name in this example and that is to be expected considering how the code you listed works. `QOpenGLExtensions` only loads extension functions for itself, not the entire application.

Comment: But they are being called from there, look at the error: glGenBuffers *referenced in* function "public: bool __cdecl QOpenGLBuffer::create(void)"

So unless he has his own QOpenGLBuffer class...